# Is there a .NET RallyRestApi method that uses the apiKey?

Tags: .net, rally

I would like to have my C# application make a connection to Rally using an API Key, but I have not found a method that supports it similar to the JAVA method:

public RallyRestApi(URI server, String apiKey)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll probably get good answers if you show some effort in your question. Rally has a .NET toolkit, did you look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this syntax:

```
restApi = new RallyRestApi( "_abc123","https://rally1.rallydev.com");
```

where "_abc123" is the key you generated using [Rally Application Manager](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-application-manager).

I noticed that the documentation does not mention this method of authentication and still shows the old username/password method in the [user guide](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/wiki/User-Guide) but a [commit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/tree/master/Rally.RestApi) was made a months ago to support ApiKeys. You have to use 2.0.1 version.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Works well, but now I am having web proxy issues.  Is there an overloaded method which takes in WebProxy?

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of Rally before, but looking right in the [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rally/info):

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("myuser@company.com", "password",
  "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.40");
```

Right in the [first page](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/wiki/User-Guide) of the documentation of the [Rally toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET).