# Using the .Net RestApi login with an account on the SSO exception list

Tags: .net, rally

So it looks like the SSO login is not supported with the .Net RestAPI.

I was told to use a login that is on the SSO exception list. We currently have two that we use to log into Rally using a Java interface and a Login key. The implementation of the .Net RestAPI needs the username and password but I have a username and a login key.

How do I use the login key as the password?

What I have tried so far is not working and if anyone has some experience with this I would like to know how they configured the Login code.
This is what I have tried.

```
          ConnectionInfo cInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
          cInfo.authType =  AuthorizationType.Basic;
          cInfo.server = new Uri("https://rally1.rallydev.com");
          cInfo.username = [email address]
          cInfo.password = [Login key];
          restAPI = new RallyRestApi(cInfo);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct - [Rally REST toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET) does not support SSO at this point. The user whose credentials you want to use to connect to Rally via the toolkit will have to be added to SSO exceptions list.

If by "Login Key" you mean API Key, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789506/is-there-a-net-rallyrestapi-method-that-uses-the-apikey).

```
restApi = new RallyRestApi( "_abc123","https://rally1.rallydev.com");
```

where "_abc123" is the key.

API Key does not work with SSO. Regardless whether you use username/passoword or API Key it will only work with Rally authentication.

If by "Login Key" you mean this [LoginKey](https://github.com/RallyTools/Login-Component-Example) it will not work since LoginKey is a legacy feature that worked only with legacy javascript [AppSDK1](https://help.rallydev.com/app-sdk).

Comment: Thanks for the Info How do I create a API Key using an account that is on the SSO exception list but we only have the LoginKey for it?

Comment: If it is a valid account that you or someone else in your organization knows username/password for, then those credentials have to be used to create ApiKey. LoginKey cannot be used to create API Key, nor it should be used to determine the read-only username and password of the original user. Your subscription administrator may either reset the password, or initiate the reset, or even disable the original user of this LoginKey and create a new user for the purposes this custom automation,integration with Rally that you are writing.